# AWS CDK: How to create a Lambda function from an existing Docker image on ECR repo?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a Docker image pushed already on ECR. I have also used it to create lambda function from a container image through AWS console, and it worked successfully.

Now, I want to create the function through AWS CDK.

Inside the `__init__` function of the lambda stack class, I have added:

```
repo = aws_ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(scope, "Repository", repository_name="my-repo-name")
lambdaFn = aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(
    self, "Test Function",
    code=aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(repo),
    timeout=core.Duration.seconds(600),
    memory_size=8192,
    environment=dict(PATH="/opt"),
    role = role
)
```

I have an issue with defining `repo` variable from an existing repo on ECR.

Answer (score 8):

**Solved!**

The code shows an error: `jsii.errors.JSIIError: Import at 'Repository' should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found`

The first attribute of `Repository` object should be `self` to refer to the same scope of the stack.

**Soultion:**

```
repo = aws_ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(self, "Repository", repository_name="my-repo-name")
lambdaFn = aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(
    self, "Test Function",
    code=aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(
        repository=repo,
        tag="latest"
    ),
    timeout=core.Duration.seconds(600),
    memory_size=8192,
    environment=dict(PATH="/opt"),
    role = role
)
```

Optionally, I have explicitly specified also the parameter `tag` as per Miguel answer.